# how to create temporal files in c

Tags: c

I have an double array and I need to store it in a file created by my source code. I know it has something to do with fget but I'm not sure how to use it exactly. example

```
weight[j][i]=lineweight(line1,line2);
FILE file=weight[j][i];
```

Comment: If you're trying to read data from the file you might want to look at fopen, fclose, fgets, and/or fread.  If you're trying to write data to a file have a look at fopen, fclose, fprintf, and fputs.  Good luck.

Comment: Read about: fopen(), fclose(), fgetc(), fgets(), fputc(), fputs(), fprintf(), fread(), fwrite(), feof(), tmpnam(), tmpfile(), etc etc.

Comment: i want my code to generate the file and delete it after execution

Answer (score 2):

Googling for "c temporary file" gives you [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Temporary-Files.html), for example, which contains a list of functions. Try `tmpfile()`.

But you probably want to save to a certain file. Use `fopen` for that and then `fwrite` or `fprintf()` to write data into it.